# Postgresql use more than one row as expression in sub query

Tags: postgresql, subquery, pivot, postgresql-9.1, crosstab

As the title says, I need to create a query where I `SELECT` all items from one table and use those items as expressions in another query. Suppose I have the main table that looks like this:

```
main_table
-------------------------------------
id | name | location | //more columns
---|------|----------|---------------
 1 | me   | pluto    | //
 2 | them | mercury  | //
 3 | we   | jupiter  | //
```

And the sub query table looks like this:

```
some_table
---------------
id | item
---|-----------
 1 | sub-col-1
 2 | sub-col-2
 3 | sub-col-3
```

where each item in `some_table` has a price which is in an `amount_table` like so:

```
amount_table
--------------
 1 | 1000
 2 | 2000
 3 | 3000
```

So that the query returns results like this:

```
name | location | sub-col-1 | sub-col-2 | sub-col-3 |
----------------------------------------------------|
me   | pluto    | 1000      |           |           |
them | mercury  |           | 2000      |           |
we   | jupiter  |           |           | 3000      |
```

My query currently looks like this

```
SELECT name, location, (SELECT item FROM some_table)
FROM main_table
INNER JOIN amount_table WHERE //match the id's
```

But I'm running into the error `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`

How can I formulate this query to return the desired results?

Comment: if you want several rows from some_table to match one in select (the reason for error) you should join it, not use in subquery, and if you want one to one raletion - you can use it as you do now, but modify `SELECT item FROM some_table` tu return one row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should decide on expected result.

to get one-tp-many relation:

```
SELECT name, location, some_table.item
FROM main_table
JOIN some_table on true -- or id if they match
INNER JOIN amount_table --WHERE match the id's
```

to get one-to-one with all rows:

```
SELECT name, location, (SELECT array_agg(item) FROM some_table)
FROM main_table
INNER JOIN amount_table --WHERE //match the id's
```